# Firebase and Auth0 integration with Instagram for mobile

Tags: android, ios, instagram-api, firebase-authentication, auth0

Is it possible to retrieve user information from instagram using Auth0 authentication and to be accessed with firebase console?

Comment: I am trying it, but for iOS. No useful documentation. :((